# Using Unity 2 InjectionProperty with a abstract base controller in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, unity-container

I have the following base controller:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller
{
    public IFormsAuthentication FormsAuthentication { get; set; }
    public IAccountRepository AccountRepository { get; set; }
}
```

I have the following code to setup Unity:

```
.RegisterType<BaseController>(new InjectionProperty[]
    {
        new InjectionProperty("FormsAuthentication", new ResolvedParameter<IFormsAuthentication>()),
        new InjectionProperty("AccountRepository", new ResolvedParameter<IAccountRepository>())
    });
```

My controller factory looks like:

```
protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
{
    return (controllerType == null) ? base.GetControllerInstance(requestContext, controllerType) : container.Resolve<IController>(controllerType);
}
```

When I try to use AccountRepository from a controller inheriting from the base controller, this setup will not work. I have no problem doing constructor injection in the controller inheriting from the base controller but can't get the property injection to work in the base controller. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Same here with Unity.MVC3 - can configure the base properties on all of the derived controllers, but not a DRY solution on just the one base.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to get Setter injection working on a base Controller class (with Unity.MVC3). I did need to explicitly provide the `[Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Dependency]` Attribute on the base however.

Base Controller:

```
    [Dependency]
    public IMyServiceDependency MyServiceDependency
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

There was nothing special needed in the configuration.

```
            <register
 type="Project.NameSpace.Interfaces.IMyServiceDependency, Project.NameSpace.Assembly"
 mapTo="Project.NameSpace.MyServiceDependency, Project.NameSpace.Assembly">
            </register>
```